# What character builds and item combinations work well in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I've been playing Terraria, and I have reached the state where I have more weapons, potions, armor types, spells and magical items than I can conveniently carry. So I've been wondering: **Which items work best with each other?** And amongst those different combinations, which is considered stronger?

For example, I know that the Space Gun is supposed to work well with the Meteor Armor. But what other items work well with them? And, on the other hand, what combination is good for high melee DPS? Or for a ranged weapon?

Or is trying to create an item combination that works well together not that beneficial? Should I only take my best armor, my 3 best weapons and my 3 favorite potions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not the best person to answer this, but here is what I know:

- Jungle and Meteor Armors work better with Spells as they provide Mana Regen and Magic Damage.
- Necro Armor works better with Bows and Guns as it increases Ranged Damage and reduces Ammo Consumption.
- Shadow and Molten Armors work better with melee weapons as they increase Attack Speed and Damage, respectively.

So loosely, I'd say:

- Ranged: Necro
- Magic: Jungle/Meteor
- Melee: Shadow/Molten

### Some example builds

#### Tank

- Molten Armor
- Cobalt Shield
- Obsidian Skull
- Ironskin Potion
- Feral Claws
- Anklet of the Wind

I've tried running this build without the Anklet, but inevitably, I need the move speed to be effective in PvP. You can swap the Anklet for Hermes Boots if you're quick with the Grappling Hook (which can accelerate you to full speed).

#### DPS

- Shadow Armor
- Muramasa
- Feral Claws
- Rocket Boots
- Hermes Boots
- Band of Regeneration

I find myself relying more on speed with this build than anything else. You're very susceptible to a fast attacking ranged build, but most melee builds don't hit the speed of Shadow+Feral+Muramasa, so I usually find I can trade 1-3 on hits.

You can read about other people's suggestions [here](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Guide:PvP#Roles_and_strategies).

Comment: @lunboks my understanding is that Feral Claws [stack](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Feral_Claws)

Comment: Well, they do not. You can't equip two of the same accessories.

Comment: _You can't equip two of the same accessories_ This applies to 1.0.6+ patch levels. In 1.0.5 game version and lower you can equip as many same accessories as much slots do you have :-)

Comment: One suggestion for the DPS example builds. You can combine accessories using the Tinker's Workshop, which can be bought from the Goblin Tinkerer. The Rocket Boots and Hermes Boots can be combined into Specter Boots, which frees up a slot.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you like to use.

Examples)

Melee set) Full Molten, obsidian skull, lucky horshoe, rocket boots, Night's Edge and other extendables.

Magic set) Full Jungle, Mana ring, lucky horshoe, rocket boots, Demon scythe and other extendables.

Answer (score 0):

i have only out about 60 hrs into the game so far but i have that jungle boomerang and blade of grass.
they work well with gold armour and its enough to defeat eye of culthu and eater of worlds

:)  BUT anything higher would be mad too....
jungle weapons r easiers to get for newbies.. but be careful in underground jungle

Answer (score -2):

1. The best set is different in different versions of game. Because with each patch level developers change items properties to make game balance better. Please write what version of game do you play.
2. Also the best items set will be different for single player game and for multiplayer PvP. Because in PvP different players will take different roles.

You can find a lot of useful information about building your hero [here](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Guide:PvP) or [here](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/PvP)

Also try to find you most favourite gameplay style and then combine items to play it.

Comment: Why "-1"???????

Comment: I didn't put it there, so I can't say... :)

Comment: and to your questions: I'm referring to the latest version of the game (1.0.6.1 as of now). I'm happy to get builds for single player, multiplayer and even PvP.

Comment: I didn't and won't downvote. But if I did, it'd be because the answer is vague; any specific information requires going to the link; the two links are purely about PvP; and the bit where you question the OP about his version of Terraria really belongs in a comment on the original question, not in an answer.